# Python 2.7 serial ubuntu

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, serial-port

I reinstalled and changed OS from Debian8 to Ubuntu18.04, and have troubles with manage Serial(USB) ports via Python2.7.

My steps are:

```
sudo apt-get install python-serial

pip install pyserial
Requirement already satisfied: pyserial in ./venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (3.4)

# usermod -a -G dialout wiks
$ getent group dialout
dialout:x:20:wiks
```

piece of code:

```
    for port in ports_list:
        try:
            s = serial.Serial(port,
                              timeout=1.0)
            s.close()
            result.append(port)
        # except (OSError, serial.SerialException):
        #     log_at.debug('problem with %s ', unicode(port))
        except Exception, e:
            log_at.debug('problem with %s --> %s [USER: %s ]', unicode(port), e, get_username())
```

but when I start script it give me:

```
2018-12-31 12:42:51.536  DEBUG     at               all in OS ports: ['/dev/ttyUSB6', '/dev/ttyUSB5', '/dev/ttyUSB4', '/dev/ttyUSB3', '/dev/ttyUSB2', '/dev/ttyUSB1', '/dev/ttyUSB0', '/dev/ttyprintk', '/dev/ttyS4', '/dev/ttyS31', '/dev/ttyS30', '/dev/ttyS29', '/dev/ttyS28', '/dev/ttyS27', '/dev/ttyS26', '/dev/ttyS25', '/dev/ttyS24', '/dev/ttyS23', '/dev/ttyS22', '/dev/ttyS21', '/dev/ttyS20', '/dev/ttyS19', '/dev/ttyS18', '/dev/ttyS17', '/dev/ttyS16', '/dev/ttyS15', '/dev/ttyS14', '/dev/ttyS13', '/dev/ttyS12', '/dev/ttyS11', '/dev/ttyS10', '/dev/ttyS9', '/dev/ttyS8', '/dev/ttyS7', '/dev/ttyS6', '/dev/ttyS5', '/dev/ttyS3', '/dev/ttyS2', '/dev/ttyS1', '/dev/ttyS0']
2018-12-31 12:42:51.536  DEBUG     at               problem with /dev/ttyUSB6 --> 'module' object has no attribute 'Serial' [USER: wiks ]
2018-12-31 12:42:51.536  DEBUG     at               problem with /dev/ttyUSB5 --> 'module' object has no attribute 'Serial' [USER: wiks ]
...
```

or even:

```
File "/home/wiks/Dokumenty/projects/sms/sms/find_serial.py", line 73, in serial_ports
except (OSError, serial.SerialException):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SerialException'
```

...when I try to catch **serial.SerialException**

I have no Idea, anybody helps?

And ...is there way to avoid **# usermod -a -G dialout wiks** before first start?

Comment: Editor note: I just translated one hilarious misspelling of "ubuntu" to another one. No offence meant to any members of the Bantu tribe. Feel free to fix.

Comment: Solved! After: **sudo apt-get purge python-serial** works. ...and any other way to avoid **# usermod -a -G dialout wiks** ?